# Socket (SOCK_RAW + IPPROTO_ICMP) can't read TTL response

Tags: sockets, icmp, ttl

I've created a ping utility on Windows. I'm using a raw socket with a ICMP protocol. I'm local administrator of my computer.

As there a lot of code, I don't want to paste it here but I found an example that is really similar to mine [winsock2advancedrawsocket11b](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedrawsocket11b.html)http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedrawsocket11b.html

I download it, test I conclude that it has the same problem as mine. I'm not receiving response when TTL expired (in IP header). I though that using RAW socket let me read that ?

Let's say I want to force a "ttl expired" on a ping, so I send a ping to "google.com" with a ttl of 2.

```
ping -i 2 -n 1 google.com
```

This give me the following result

```
Reply from 204.80.6.137: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 204.80.6.137: TTL expired in transit.
```

Using my application I send the same ping request and see what I received in Wireshark. I got one ICMP packet sent to google and another packet from my router telling me that TTL has expired. So, why a raw socket on Windows is not receiving this message too ? Is there an option to force reading ip header even if the TTL is expired ?

So I presume that Windows `ping.exe` utility is filtering packet better/different than what we can do with the Winsock API ?

As reference, this is how the socket is created :

```
#include <winsock2.h> 
#include <ws2tcpip.h> 
#include <mstcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct IPV4_HDR
{
    unsigned char ip_header_len : 4;
    unsigned char ip_version : 4;
    unsigned char ip_tos;
    unsigned short ip_total_length;
    unsigned short ip_id;

    unsigned char ip_frag_offset : 5;

    unsigned char ip_more_fragment : 1;
    unsigned char ip_dont_fragment : 1;
    unsigned char ip_reserved_zero : 1;

    unsigned char ip_frag_offset1;

    unsigned char ip_ttl;
    unsigned char ip_protocol;
    unsigned short ip_checksum;
    unsigned int ip_srcaddr;
    unsigned int ip_destaddr;
};

struct ICMP_HDR
{
    BYTE type;
    BYTE code;
    USHORT checksum;
    USHORT id;
    USHORT seq;
};

unsigned short compute_checksum(unsigned short* buffer, int size)
{
    unsigned long cksum = 0;
    while (size > 1)
    {
        cksum += *buffer++;
        size -= sizeof(unsigned short);
    }
    if (size)
    {
        cksum += *(char*)buffer;
    }

    cksum = (cksum >> 16) + (cksum & 0xffff);
    cksum += (cksum >> 16);
    return (unsigned short)(~cksum);
}

void send_receive_ping(SOCKET icmp_sock)
{
    std::vector<char> receive_buffer;
    receive_buffer.resize(65536);
    std::fill(receive_buffer.begin(), receive_buffer.end(), 0);
    char *Buffer = receive_buffer.data();

    int recv_bytes = 0;
    DWORD start_time = GetTickCount();
    bool first_time_in_loop = true;
    do
    {
        if ( (first_time_in_loop == true 
            || GetTickCount() - start_time > 5000))
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Sending an ICMP packet....\n");
            send_icmp_packet(icmp_sock);

            first_time_in_loop = false;
            start_time = GetTickCount();
        }

        recv_bytes = recvfrom(icmp_sock, Buffer, 65536, 0, 0, 0);
        if (recv_bytes > 0)
        {
            // Handle received packet
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (recv_bytes > 0);
}

void send_icmp_packet(SOCKET icmp_sock)
{
    sockaddr_in sockaddr_in_dst = {};
    sockaddr_in_dst.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr_in_dst.sin_port = 0;
    sockaddr_in_dst.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("184.150.168.247"); // google.com

    std::vector<char> send_buffer;
    send_buffer.resize(sizeof(IPV4_HDR) + sizeof(ICMP_HDR));
    std::fill(send_buffer.begin(), send_buffer.end(), 0);

    IPV4_HDR *ipv4_header = (IPV4_HDR *)send_buffer.data();
    ipv4_header->ip_header_len = 5;
    ipv4_header->ip_version = 4;
    ipv4_header->ip_tos = 16;
    ipv4_header->ip_total_length = htons( send_buffer.size() );
    ipv4_header->ip_id = htons(0);
    ipv4_header->ip_ttl = 64;
    //ipv4_header->ip_ttl = 2;
    ipv4_header->ip_protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP;
    ipv4_header->ip_srcaddr = dest.sin_addr.s_addr;
    ipv4_header->ip_destaddr = sockaddr_in_dst.sin_addr.s_addr;
    ipv4_header->ip_checksum = compute_checksum((unsigned short *)ipv4_header, sizeof(IPV4_HDR));

    static unsigned short seq = 0;
    ICMP_HDR *icmp_header = (ICMP_HDR *)(send_buffer.data() + sizeof(IPV4_HDR));
    icmp_header->type = 8;
    icmp_header->seq = seq++;
    icmp_header->id = 888;
    icmp_header->checksum = compute_checksum((unsigned short *)icmp_header, sizeof(ICMP_HDR));

    ret = sendto(icmp_sock, (char *)send_buffer.data(), send_buffer.size(),
        0, (sockaddr *)&sockaddr_in_dst, sizeof(sockaddr_in_dst));
}


int main()
{
    WSADATA ws;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &ws);

    SOCKET icmp_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);

    char hostname[256];
    gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));

    hostent *local = gethostbyname(hostname);

    sockaddr_in source;
    memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
    memcpy(&source.sin_addr.s_addr, local->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(source.sin_addr.s_addr));
    source.sin_family = AF_INET;
    source.sin_port = 0;

    bind(icmp_sock, (sockaddr *)&source, sizeof(source));

    int recv_all_opt = 1;
    int ioctl_read = 0;
    WSAIoctl(icmp_sock, SIO_RCVALL, &recv_all_opt, sizeof(recv_all_opt), 0, 0, (LPDWORD)&ioctl_read, 0, 0);

    int ip_header_include = 1;
    setsockopt(icmp_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&ip_header_include, sizeof(ip_header_include));

    send_receive_ping(icmp_sock);

    closesocket(icmp_sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

The preceding code seems to work pretty well but I'm still unable to get the expired TLL from IP message. It's like the OS steals the package. I bet is because I ask to read ICMP message and the TLL is in the IP header. So if the IP header is faulty than the OS discard the message and my socket can't read it. So I tried using a socket IPPROTO_IP :

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
```

I'm still not getting TTL expired message, worst I'm loosing packet sometime. I saw them in Wireshark but I'm not getting them on my socket. Is someone having an idea why ?

Comment: It likely doesn't work because the reply is coming from a different IP then you send the request to. You might have to put the socket into promiscuous mode (via `WSAIoctl(SIO_RCVALL)`) to receive packets from other IPs, and then filter the results as needed. Or at least `bind()` the socket before sending the request, so you can use `send()` and `recv()` and let them handle ICMP errors internally. But, is there a reason why you are doing this manually instead of just using the `IcmpSendEcho()` family of functions instead?

Comment: Hi Remy, I'm doing it manually as I need a cross platform solution linux/windows and also I need to stop the process quickly at any time.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But the socket must be bind to a specific interface else it does not work. Thus we can't bind on `INADDR_ANY` else we get a `WSAEINVAL`.

Comment: Now I'm now reading a valid (IP + ICMP + Data) from recvfrom call but after looking at it this is the packet I sent not, a the reply I'm seeing in Wireshark. What's this ? From what I understand, `SIO_RCVALL` allow us to read ingoing but also outgoing packet ? I continue to try to read a couple of seconds but the reply never reach my socket ! What's wrong ? Nevertheless I saw both the request and reply in Wireshark and the reply is addressed the interface I bound.

Comment: Is it possible that Windows does not allow reading a packet having an expired TTL?

Comment: I create an issue on MSDN forum, if someone interested to follow this problem. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/0835f11d-d285-46bb-bec4-3645a16ed905/

Comment: I've implemented a ping with raw socket on Windows, it works just like system-provided ping. You should provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jify : I updated the code and now you have a complete working example.

Comment: your code works on my PC except a few compiler errors, you forgot to handle received packet when you actually received them at this line? `if (recv_bytes > 0)
{// Handle received packet}`

Comment: Hi @jify, thank you for your help. Indeed the code works properly but it does not work when creating an IP header with a very low TTL. Try to uncomment the line `//ipv4_header->ip_ttl = 2;`, send a ping to a distant server (Ex : google.cn) and you should received a TTL expired ICMP packet. But I'm not receiving it, I got a receive timeout on the socket. However I see the ICMP TTL expired reply it in Wireshark. So it means that Windows IP stack steal me the packet somewhere....

Comment: I can also get TTL expired ICMP packet. Maybe your firewall blocked it, Wireshark captures before firewall, turn off your firewall and try again.

Comment: Weird.....what Windows version you have ? I'm on `Windows 7 Pro 64 bits SP1, firewall deactivated completely behind a Windows Server 2008 SBS server domaine`. Could it be the router or the domaine ? I doubt as Wireshark would not see it ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be exactly what you suspect, Windows is diverting the TTL Exceeded responses and they don't arrive on the raw socket. I'm experiencing the same issue, and the best explanation I've found so far is [this discussion of porting the MTR traceroute-style utility to Windows](https://github.com/traviscross/mtr/issues/55#issuecomment-257780611).

What's really sad is that IT USED TO WORK on Windows 7 back in 2012-2013 when I first started working with raw sockets in the Windows environment. A few years went by and all of a sudden the same code on the same machine no longer receives TTL Exceeded messages.

Depending on your application, you may be able to workaround by calling ICMP.DLL directly as discussed in the link above. This code [from the P2PScrapper project](https://github.com/rabimba/p2pScrapper/blob/master/BitTorrent-5.2.2/BTL/win32icmp.py) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply allow ICMP in windows firewall. Create inbound rule, select ICMP in protocol and set 'allow'.